# Which framework is best for starting with responsive web design?

Tags: css, responsive-design

My goal is to launch websites quicker that are mobile friendly and great for different screen resolutions. Can someone with experience in CSS recommend *which CSS frameworks* are *best* to start out with:

- Zurb Foundation
- Less Framework 4
- Columnal
- Bootstrap
- Frameless

What are the *pros and cons* for each of them? Feel free to suggest anything not listed.

Once the site is built can I easily add *jQuery* sliders, effects or animations?

Comment: Zurb has just released the new version of Foundation with some great documentation. As mentioned the ALA RWD book is a great starting place. If you want to learn about RWD, build it up from scratch starting with mobile first. If you want to knock out fast websites on a grid based responsive framework then go one that you mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, there's one book that explains anything and everything you might want to know.  If you're just beginning to get into responsive web design, I'd start with this:

[Responsive Web Design - Ethan Marcotte](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design/)

To my understanding, Ethan is known as the "guy who started the movement".  I can personally attest that the book has been of immense help to me.  I'm not even sure quite frankly that you need to use a framework.  If you code your website with the best practices the first time and build it as fluid as possible (even if you wrap within a 960px wide div) then resizing downwards from there using CSS media queries is a snap.  I'd also check out the book [Mobile First by Luke Wroblewski](http://www.abookapart.com/products/mobile-first).

[You can even buy these books as a bundle.](http://www.abookapart.com/products/mobile-first-responsive-web-design-bundle)  They're quick reads, you can read each of them in an afternoon.  These two books got me into responsive web design, I couldn't suggest checking them out enough!

Answer (score 16):

I have read both books mentioned which are great.

I really like Zurb Foundation. I have built a few sites with it and had no issues. I have found it easy to extend - it's easy to build a prototype that and then take to full production. (I've been using version 2 - there is V3 out - however V3 has dropped support for IE7)

A new tool someone in the office was playing with was jetstrap.com

Let's you visually do responsive layouts - you can then check the code and see how it's done and might be a good way to get started.

Comment: +1 for Zurb Foundation, it's dramatically decreased my build time whilst giving me a responsive layout foundation.

Comment: Good answer Jules, especially with the mention of Jetstrap!  You deserve the correct answer if you ask me.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

There's also:

- *320 & Up* by Andy Clarke, which is based on a *mobile comes first* design (so, it's good for that) - http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/
- and *Gumby*, which got some really good reviews - http://www.gumbyframework.com/

I can't really help as I'm still too yet to try one of these responsive frameworks out. I too wish to know the pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Gumby Framework.  And before working with Gumby and others, you should have an understanding what's going on.. hence reading Ethan Marcotte's book.